# xvalue's lifetime bound to reference extended or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Apparently there is some confusion and differences between compilers as regards this issue:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c754c4e-5471-4095-afae-795c1f411612/rvalue-refs-extended-lifetime-inconsistent-with-gccstandard

According to this post:

[What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Xvalues are rvalues (along with prvalues) and the standard says:

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The
>   temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the
>   complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the reference except:

However there exist posts that dispute this:

[Do rvalue references allow dangling references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716277/do-rvalue-references-allow-dangling-references/3716360#3716360)

[What is an example of a difference in allowed usage or behavior between an xvalue and a prvalue FOR NON-POD objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482508/what-is-an-example-of-a-difference-in-allowed-usage-or-behavior-between-an-xvalu)

Can someone please clarify the issue. Is MSVC right for once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xvalues may be rvalues, but that doesn't mean that they are *temporaries*. The lifetime extension of temporaries comes from the fact that they're *temporaries*, not their value category.

I deliberately try not to know the order in which operators are processed (that way, I force myself to write code that either uses explicit parentheses or doesn't care about the order). Your specific `adder` example code, reproduced here, does care:

```
template <class T>
struct addable
{
    friend T operator +( const T& lhs, const T& rhs )
    {
        return std::move(T(lhs) += rhs); 
    }
    friend T operator +( const T& lhs, T&& rhs )
    {
        return std::move(T(lhs) += std::move(rhs));
    }   
    friend T&& operator +( T&& lhs, const T& rhs ) 
    {
        return std::move(lhs += rhs);
    }               
    friend T&& operator +( T&& lhs, T&& rhs ) 
    {
        return std::move(lhs += std::move(rhs)); 
    }
};
```

If the `+` operator is done right-to-left, then `t1 + t2 + t3` will work out to `t1 + (t2 + t3)`. `t2 + t3` will call the first overload, thus producing a *temporary*, thus yielding `t1 + temp`. Since a temporary will preferentially bind to an r-value reference, that expression will call the second overload, which will *also* return a temporary.

However, if the `+` operator works left-to-right, then you get `(t1 + t2) + t3`. This gives us `temp + t1`, which causes a problem. It will call the third overload. The `lhs` parameter of that function is a `T&&`, a reference to the temporary. You return the same reference. Which means you have returned a reference to a temporary. But C++ doesn't know that; all it knows is that you're returning a reference to something.

That "something" however is due to be destroyed after the final expression (the assignment to the new variable, either a value type or a reference type) has been evaluated. Remember: C++ doesn't know that this function will return a reference to it's first parameter. So it has no way of knowing that the lifetime of a temporary passed to a function operand needs to be extended to the lifetime where the returned reference is stored.

Incidentally, this is why expression trees can be dangerous with `auto` and such lurking about. Because the inner temporaries created cannot be preserved by new temporaries or references stored in various objects. C++ just doesn't have a way to do that.

So who's right depends on which order the operators are resolved in. However, I prefer my solution: don't rely on these corners of the language and just work around them. Stop returning `T&&` from these overloads and just move the value to a temporary. That way, it's guaranteed to work correctly and you don't have to constantly check the standard to make sure your code is working.

Also, as an aside, I would consider it somewhat rude for operator+ to actually *modify* one of the parameters.

However, if you insist on knowing who's right, it's GCC. From section 5.7, p1:

> The additive operators + and - group left-to-right.

So yes, it shouldn't work.

Note: Visual Studio allows `T &r2 = t1 + t2 + t3;` to compile as a (highly annoying) language extension. You should hopefully have gotten a warning from it.

Comment: I am not the poster on M$'s site, just confused. I am not even using MSVC, but I do worry about the meaning of my code.

Comment: @user1095108: I added an addendum at the bottom.

Comment: You've explained nicely, but could you point to relevant sections of the standard as well? If I understand correctly returning a rvalue reference to a temporary automatically leads to a dangling reference.

Comment: @user1095108: You already pointed out the relevant sections of the standard in your question. The temporary produced from `t1 + t2` was bound to a reference. Namely, *the function parameter*. It's lifetime was extended to the lifetime of that variable. Namely, the duration of the function. Thus, it's fundamentally no different from returning a reference to a stack variable.

Comment: And what do you mean with "Xvalues may be rvalues", they _are_ rvalues.

Comment: @user1095108: I mean that in the general way that "X may be Y, but it isn't Z" is typically used in the English language. The point being that whether X is a Y is irrelevant, because what's relevant is that X isn't a Z.

Comment: no. "t1 + t2" will have full expression lifetime... binding by a reference function parameter does not limit its lifetime...